# why a reduced ring can be embedded into a sum of integral rings?

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, ag.algebraic-geometry

Hi,
the question is exactly
"why a reduced ring (commutative with 1) can be embedded into a sum of integral rings?"
Is this simply because in the normalization process we can have many irreducible component?

Comment: This seems a little too elementary for MO; see the FAQ. Perhaps you should ask on math.stackexchange.com instead.

Comment: Note that this question *has* been asked -- and answered, and the answer has been accepted -- on math.SE.  

Comment: Hint: In a reduced ring, the intersection of all prime ideals is $0$.

Comment: @OP: by sum you probably mean product. 